# Download Gridview Error data

Tags: asp.net

I am working on a project, where  I want to download gridview row data, but it is not working for me. Here is the code i used for download:

```
string fileName = "chhattisgarhishafte" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + ".doc";
                    GridView1.DataSource = dtD;
                    GridView1.DataBind();

                    Response.Clear();
                    Response.Buffer = true;

                    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName);
                    Response.Charset = "";
                    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-word ";
                    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

                    GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
                    GridView1.DataBind();

                    GridView1.RenderBeginTag(hw);
                    GridView1.RenderControl(hw);
                    Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
                    GridView1.RenderEndTag(hw);
                    Response.Flush();
                    Response.End();
```

stD is datatble which stores the gridview selected rows.

The errror is:

```
Control 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1' of type 'GridView' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.
```

Comment: please add the markup code from your .aspx file. The error indicates, something is wrong there

Comment: download grid data in word or excel?

Answer (score 0):

Please use in form tag in the master page use runat="server"

Comment: the page is under contentpage of masterpage..And in this page the gridview is under update panel.

Comment: Since you are using Update panel that is why page is not postback remove update panel or use asynchronous post back on click of the download button

Answer (score 0):

use this code,its working in my application

```
            if (gv.Rows.Count > 0)
            {

                StringWriter tw = new StringWriter();
                HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);

                //Get the HTML for the control.
                gv.RenderControl(hw);
                //Write the HTML back to the browser.
                //Response.ContentType = application/vnd.ms-excel;
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + strFileName);
                EnableViewState = false;
                Response.Write(tw.ToString());
                Response.End();
            }
```

Comment: when program control comes to line:-  GridView1.RenderControl(hw);,Then it show error:--Control 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1' of type 'GridView' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.

Comment: I am downloading gridview data in ms-word